# Ejecutable Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Ya converti mi ejecutable Java a .exe pero cuando ejecuto el .exe ingreso al logueo y le doy aceptar me sale el siguiente error:

> "Este controlador no esta configurado para la autenticacion
>   integrada".

Esta es mi conexion a la base de datos sql server:

```
public Connection getConectar(){
        Connection cn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                   "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;
                   databaseName=FEBAN_PRUEBA_ERP;integratedSecurity=true;");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:"+" "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return cn;
    }
```

en el run configurations, en la opcion arguments escribo la ruta donde está ubicado el dll sqljdbc_auth.dll

Comment: Te aseguraste que tienes la versión de `sqljdbc_auth.dll` que corresponde en la ruta? Hace una diferencia si apuntas a la versión x86 o la versión x64 dependiente de que tipo de Java usas (32bit o 64bit).

Comment: estoy usuando la version de sqljdbc_auth.dll x86

Comment: Y tu app corre en Java 32bit entonces?

Comment: si en 32 bits..

Comment: Cada vez que ejecuto el aplicativo me sale error: "Este controlador no esta configurado para la autenticacion integrada".

Comment: Eso se entiende desde tu pregunta. Una razón posible para eso podría ser  que tienes el `sqljdbc_auth.dll` equivocado en tu ruta, asumiendo que la ruta en si esta bien configurado. Pero si estas seguro que la VM tal cual como el dll son de 32bit el problema debería ser otro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te copio traducido lo que dice [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx#Connectingintegrated) sobre tu asunto:

> **Connecting with Integrated Authentication**
>
> The JDBC driver supports the
>   use of Type 2 integrated authentication on Windows operating systems
>   through the integratedSecurity connection string property. To use
>   integrated authentication, copy the sqljdbc_auth.dll file to a
>   directory on the Windows system path on the computer where the JDBC
>   driver is installed. The sqljdbc_auth.dll files are installed in the
>   following location: \sqljdbc_\\auth\
>
> ***Note***: If you are running a 32-bit Java Virtual Machine (JVM), use the sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the x86 folder, even if the operating system is the x64 version. If you are running a 64-bit JVM on a x64 processor, use the sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the x64 folder. If you are running a 64-bit  JVM on a IA-64 processor, use the sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the IA64
>    folder. Alternatively you can set the java.libary.path system property
>    to specify the directory of the sqljdbc_auth.dll. For example, if the
>    JDBC driver is installed in the default directory, you can specify the
>    location of the DLL by using the following virtual machine (VM)
>    argument when the Java application is started:
>
> -Djava.library.path=C:\Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver\sqljdbc_\enu\auth\x86
>
> ---
>
> **Conexión con autenticación integrada**
>
> El controlador JDBC admite el uso de la autenticación integrada de
>   tipo 2 en los sistemas operativos Windows a través de la propiedad de
>   cadena de conexión integratedSecurity. Para utilizar la autenticación
>   integrada, **copie el archivo `sqljdbc_auth.dll` a un directorio en la
>   ruta del sistema de Windows en el equipo donde está instalado el
>   controlador JDBC**. Los archivos `sqljdbc_auth.dll` se instalan en la
>   ubicación siguiente: `<installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\auth\`
>
> ***Nota***:
>
> 1. Si está ejecutando una máquina virtual Java de 32 bits (JVM), utilice el archivo `sqljdbc_auth.dll` en la carpeta `x86`, incluso si el sistema operativo es la versión `x64`.
> 2. Si está ejecutando una JVM de 64 bits en un procesador x64, utilice el
>      archivo `sqljdbc_auth.dll` en la carpeta `x64`.
> 3. Si está ejecutando una JVM de 64 bits en un procesador IA-64, utilice el archivo `sqljdbc_auth.dll`en la carpeta `IA64`.
>
> También puede configurar la propiedad del sistema `java.libary.path` para especificar el directorio del `sqljdbc_auth.dll`.
>   Por ejemplo, si el controlador JDBC está instalado en el directorio
>   predeterminado, puede especificar la ubicación de la DLL mediante el
>   siguiente argumento de máquina virtual (VM) cuando se inicia la
>   aplicación Java:
>
> `-Djava.library.path=C:\Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver\sqljdbc_<version>\enu\auth\x86`

**Cadenas de conexión**
Imagino que tus cadenas de conexión están bien. De todos modos, pongo aquí algunos ejemplos [tomados de Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx):

Connect to the default database on the local computer by using integrated authentication:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Connect to a named database on a remote server:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Connect on the default port to the remote server:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Connect by specifying a customized application name:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;applicationName=MyApp;
```